# Simulation of gravity : velocity goes to infinity when distance is zero

Tags: newtonian-gravity, simulations

I tried to implement an N-Body simulation. Everything works, but when particles go very close to each others, the energy (hence the velocity) tends to $∞$, making a very high social distancing and "bounce", making the simulation fairly inaccurate over time. How can I fix that ?

I can't access to the code right now but it's a simple iterative solver, calculating the energy at each time, then updating the acceleration, then the velocity, and then the position.

Comment: The nature of the problem (inverse square law) is the primary cause, but the integrator method usually makes things much worse. Please [edit] your question and add some implementation details on the simulation, which would be the first thing to tackle here. Specifically the integrator part that updates velocities in future time frames.

Comment: [See this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method) describing how you need to implement an adaptive step size for _n_-body simulations.